# How do you fill entire Button area with background View in WatchOS?

Tags: swift, swiftui, apple-watch, watchos

I am trying to have my background view span the entire area of a Button on an Apple Watch form factor.

```
struct SurveyView: View {

var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        print("Test tapped.")
    }) {
        HStack {
            Text("Test")
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.green, .blue]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))


     }
   }
}
```

[image]

How can I make the background span the entire Button?

**Update:** Turns out my issue is also related to being in a List View. Setting a mask doesn't quite solve it.

```
struct SurveyView: View {

var body: some View {
    List() {
        Button(action: {
            print("Test tapped.")
        }) {
            Text("Test")
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
        }
        .background(Color.orange)


        .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 24))
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in the following way:

[image: SwiftUI custom background for WatchKit button]

```
Button(action: {
    print("Test tapped.")
}) {
    Text("Test")
        .fontWeight(.semibold)
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(.white)
}
.background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.green, .blue]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
.mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 24))
```

**Update:** the case for list

```
var body: some View {
    List() {
        Button(action: {
            print("Test tapped.")
        }) {
            Text("Test")
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .padding()
        }
        .background(Color.orange)
        .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 24))
        .listRowPlatterColor(Color.clear)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution for a static button. Ive updated my question to specifically ask for a Button in a List View.

Comment: is there a way to get the same result but with swift 5?